# Stop Underlying Child Sub

Tags: autohotkey

In my script there are two subs.  The Parent Sub launches the Child Sub.

Now, I want to stop the ChildSub using a hotkey, but I want the Parent sub to continue without the script terminating.

In my example here, the msgboxes will appear in order: *1*,*2*,*3*,*4*.

When I start the script, msgbox *1* will appear, but I want to push <kbd>escape</kbd> and stop the Childsub, thus I should see:  *1*,*4*

```
#SingleInstance,force

ParentSub:
    hotkey, escape, Interruptsub
    gosub, ChildSub
    msgbox 4
    return
    Interruptsub:
    exitapp
return


ChildSub:
    msgbox 1
    msgbox 2
    msgbox 3
return
```

How can I do that without adding logic inside of `ChildSub` ?

Comment: Not possible possible within the boundaries you described. You can however launch a sub in a new (real) thread using [autohotkey.dll](http://www.autohotkey.net/~HotKeyIt/AutoHotkey/files/ahkdll-txt.html). This thread will offer a function `ahkTerminate`. As before: Your example doesn't seem to represent a real problem. If you shared that problem, we would most certainly find another way.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it if your willing to edit parent sub

one problem is that hotkeys trigger a psuedo thread so the memory space of a variable is not visible in the main thread. a workaround is to create a hotkey that creates a blank file as a marker
so lets sat ctrl+1

```
^1:: fileappend, ,stopchild
```

then you add this to your parentsub

```
if !FileExist( stopchild )
gosub, ChildSub
```

a second hotkey calling filedelete will re enable the child sub

~ tank ahkscript.org

Comment: Thanks Tank.  Problem is that doesn't *stop* the `childsub` from running after it is called.  It only prevents `childsub` from running in the first place.